# Prove that the determinant of the Gram matrix of 3 vectors is nonnegative

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ to be the regular inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $y_1,y_2,y_3\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that $\det(G)\ge0$ where

$$   G := 
\begin{pmatrix}
\langle y_1,y_1\rangle & \langle y_1,y_2\rangle & \langle y_1,y_3\rangle \\
\langle y_2,y_1\rangle & \langle y_2,y_2\rangle &\langle y_2,y_3\rangle\\
\langle y_3,y_1\rangle & \langle y_3,y_2\rangle & \langle y_3,y_3\rangle
\end{pmatrix}.$$

---

I tried to open the matrix det multiply time but it didn't went through pretty good, I'd like to know if someone has any hint to give me on how to work it.
thanks!

Comment: You can find some information if you search for [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix) or Gram determinant.

Answer (score 2):

If we treat $y_1, y_2, \cdots, $ as column vectors, let $X=\begin{pmatrix} y_1 & y_2 & \cdots & y_n \end{pmatrix}$, then $G=X^tX$ which is positive semidefinite.

Comment: Hey, we haven't study the definition of a positive semidefinite, am and when I reach G=$X^TX$ I feel like I am back to the beginning

Comment: @MustangSally   $X$   is a square matrix. How does $\det X^T$ compare with $\det X$

Comment: Not really, because X is $3\times n$ because I am using $y_1,y_2,y_3$ only as my span and $y_1\in\mathbf{R}$ so using the det to prove it is a bit problematic because it is not a square matrix